# How do i style a youtube live stream message?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

Hi so i am manually inserting in my live stream using a node js googleapis/youtube package. The message shows as a plain text message, what i would like to know is how can i change the design of this text message so that it is more noticeable like maybe highlighting it? I am currently using the following code

```
const youtubeService = {};
youtubeService.insertMessage = messageText => {
console.log(myliveChatId);
const response = youtube.liveChatMessages.insert(
{
  auth: auth,
  part: 'snippet',
  resource: {
    snippet: {
      type: 'textMessageEvent',
      liveChatId: myliveChatId,
      textMessageDetails: {
        messageText: 'hello man'
      }
     }
    }
   },
   (error) => {
      console.log(error);
   }
  );
    console.log(response);
  };
```

EDIT:

This is how a chat message usually appears

[image]

what i want is something like this

[image]

Note: The message that is inserted onto my livestream via the code wont be through my account but rather someone else's.

Comment: May you precise what you mean by "highlighting it" ? A link to a documentation or a procedure or image to generate such highlighted messages (if they already exist) would be helpful. Would pinning the chat message sufficiently *style* it ?

Comment: Yes pining would work as well @BenjaminLoison

Comment: I will investigate pinning messages. I think that messages are highlighted only if the author is the YouTube channel livestreaming so it seems impossible for any other YouTube channel to have such message style.

Comment: I haven't achieved to pin automatically a message sent from the API. I would recommend you to web-scrap from the UI both sending message on your live and pinning it.